# Comparing two excel files using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am comparing two excel files that have a different number of columns and rows. I need to search for a particular value in a column but I am unable to do it as I am new to python.
This is my code:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
wk1= openpyxl.load_workbook("Condition.xlsx")
wk2= openpyxl.load_workbook("Database.xlsx")
sh1 = wk1['Sheet1']
sh2 =wk2['Sheet1']
rows1 = sh1.max_row
columns1 = sh1.max_column
rows2 = sh2.max_row
columns2 = sh2.max_column




 for i in range(2,rows2):
     c = sh1.cell(2,1).value
     if sh2.cell(i,2).value==c:
         if sh2.cell(i,3).value== 'Credit' and sh1.cell(i,3).value=='UWCC_A':
             print(sh2.cell(i,3).value)
         else:    
             print(1)   



Excel1 :

C1    C2   C3       
mike  U_11 Baseball
john  U_12 cricket
sam   U_12 Handball

Excel 2

C1    C2  C4
mike  U_11  ABC
mike  U_11  XYZ
mike  U_11  EUE
mike  U_11  PIJ
```

Comment: What does not work? Is no matching cell found?

Comment: souldn't this be i `c = sh1.cell(2,1).value`

Comment: Is the value in exactly the same position in both sheets? If not, then you need another one or two nested for loops to walk through the other sheet.

Comment: @joe I need to check for a particular value in column in a sheet and compare it with the value of another column in other sheet

Comment: @joe  one excel sheet is subset of other sheet

Comment: From simple to complex: can you just create a new excel file with two sheets, then paste something identical in the upper left cells in both sheets, then compare. If that works we go on :)

Comment: @e4c5 yes it is c = sh1.cell(i,2).value

Comment: I am adding some data to the question . please see it @Joe

Comment: I need to check that mike C2 value is same in mike C2 values in excel 2  @Joe

Comment: What does this print: `print(sh1.cell(row=1, column=2).value == sh2.cell(row=1, column=2).value)`

Comment: It is returning false @Joe

Comment: Can we select a column by name and then iterate over it for the same C1? @Joe

Comment: The sample data provided does not contain the values you're looking for.

Comment: @CharlieClark I want to check that for `mike` has the same values for other columns in excel 2

Comment: What does this return `print(sh1.cell(row=1, column=2).value, sh2.cell(row=1, column=2).value)`

Comment: @Joe it is printing different values because columns positions are different in boths sheets for C1 , Can we select a column by name and then iterate over it searching for the value from Excel 1?

Comment: Do you mean by name a "header" or the Excel label like `A1` ?

Comment: and if I want to color the cell with red color if the entry for Mike is not correct then how will I do that? @Joe

Comment: @Joe Yes Any other way

Comment: It is all pretty straight-forward. Try comparing values in a single sheet. Then try iterating, over a row or a column with a for loop and maybe paste the row and column indices in the cells. Once that works combine the techniques to what you need.

Comment: Have you done this?

Answer (score -1):

You can read from a cell alsoby using `cell('A2').value`

Coloring cells:

```
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border, colors

green = (0, 192, 0)

def iter_to_hex(x):

    #X is upper, x is lower
    return ''.join(["{:02X}".format(_) for _ in x])

print(iter_to_hex(green))

fill_green = PatternFill('solid',
                         start_color=iter_to_hex(green),
                         end_color=iter_to_hex(green))

wc = ws.cell(row=_r, column=_c)

 if _res['result']:

    wc.value = 'Something'
    wc.fill = fill_green
```

Comment: Hey @Joe can you please write the code , that how can I iterate over the column in  excel 2
 and find the required value from excel 1